# Default value in drop down

Tags: php, html, select

I am creating a edit user page which contains text boxes and drop down menus populated from data within the database.

I currently call a function to populate the drop down menus. For example, here is the code that I used to populate a drop down:

```
<select name="manager">;
<?php
// printing the list box select command
foreach($managerDetails as $row){
//Array or records stored in $managerDetails
echo "<option value='${row['userID']}'>
${row['lastName']}, ${row['firstName']}
</option>";
/* Option values are added by looping through the array */
}
?>
</select>
```

I am attempting to have the combo box automatically display the value from the database.
I have attempted placing this as the value of :

```
value="<?php echo $userDetails['managerID']; ?>"
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need the `selected` keyword. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/select

Comment: Can someone please edit this question and change _attempted placing this as the value of :_ into _attempted placing this as the value of `<select>`:_?

Comment: As every one says you need "selected" Try these examples http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/php_drop_down_list.php http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Dropdown-Select-With-PHP-and-MySQL.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo "<option value='${row['userID']}' ". (($userDetails['managerID'] == $row['userID']) ? "selected='selected'":"").">${row['lastName']}, ${row['firstName']}</option>";
```

will do

Answer (score 2):

You want to say:

```
<option selected="selected">DefaultValue</Option>
```

here is a great example:
http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlselect.php

Comment: `selected="yes"` is invalid. Please simply use `selected` or valid XHTML: `selected="selected"`.

Comment: may not be 'valid' but it still works.  Hooray for standards!

Answer (score -1):

```
<select name="manager">
    <?php
        $user_id = //the current user id selected from the database/or can get it through a login SESSION['']
        foreach($managerdetails as $row=>$d){ ?>
            <option <?php if($d == $user_id)echo "selected";?> value='${row['userID']}'><?php echo ${row['lastName']}, ${row['firstName']}?></option>
        <?php } ?>
</select>
```